# Is there any way of altering the CidrIp value of AWS security group? I just want to change the CidrIp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

How ever I tried and is generating error "The filter 'CidrIp' is invalid".

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values='*security_group_name*' Name=tag-key,Values=IpRanges Name=CidrIp,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query 'SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName,ID:GroupId}'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no API call that will modify the rule in place; they're immutable. You can only authorize or revoke security group ingress/egress rules.

Here's an example of adding the a security group ingress (assuming this is for a VPC and not the old style EC2 or your default VPC. If it is the latter, you can use --group-name instead of --group-id):

`aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxxxxxxx --protocol tcp --ports 443 --cidr "0.0.0.0/0"`

Modify the security group ID, ports, protocol, and cidr as needed. There's also an option to pass in --ip-permissions for adding multiple rules at once, but the syntax isn't as clean.

Once you've authorized the appropriate ingress rule, revoke the old one (if it exists):

`aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxxxxxxx --protocol tcp --port 80 --cidr "0.0.0.0/0"`

Review the following ec2 subcommands on the AWS CLI page for more information:

- authorize-security-group-egress
- authorize-security-group-ingress
- revoke-security-group-egress
- revoke-security-group-ingress

[AWS CLI EC2 commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ip-permission.cidr`. From [aws ec2 describe-security-groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html)

> ip-permission.cidr - An IPv4 CIDR range that has been granted
>   permission in a security group rule.